# Project downloaded from github not runing in xcode 10

Tags: swift, github, cocoapods, pch, xcodeproj

I had download a project from my git repo. In my project there are two .xcodeproj file, podfiles with some of objective c code. But is not running and giving error

I had try to edit manage schemes and also try to install/update pods but pod installation also generating error below. My idea of editing scheme also not work.

/Users/chauhan/Desktop/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjName/Pods-ProjName.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "ProjName" in project "ProjName") (in target 'ProjName')

[!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

```
project 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'
```

Click the image links to view error:-

[image: Code build error image]

[image: Pod installation error image]

Comment: Make sure you opened `.xcworkspace` file in Xcode.

Comment: @CodeChanger, I'm opening .xcworkspace fie, have cross check it again..

Comment: The error is pretty clear... There are more than one `xcodeproj` files in your folder and `pod` cannot decide in which one should install the dependencies, hence it prompts you to specify one.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had solve it out by placing second .xcodeproj file in separate folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes due to 2 .xcodeproj file in my project folder, now I create another folder for my 2nd .xcodeproj with in my project folder. It is working fine now.